# Close currentsession in Facebook login in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook-login

I m integrating Facebook login in my app.
I have a Log out button in my app.When user clicks Sign Out then Facebook's current session should be closed .Again if I click Login it should show Login screen of Facebook.
When Log out button is clicked:

```
appDelegate.fbEmail=nil;
 if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [appDelegate closeSession];
    }

AppDelegate.m

-(void)closeSession
{
     [[FBSession activeSession] close];


}
-(BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI{


    NSArray *permissions=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"email", nil];
    return[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
        [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
    }];
}
```

After he clicks logout it changes to login.Now when login is clicked Login screen of facebook should appear..How to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try FBSessionDelegate Methods? Inside FBSessionDelegate have methods to handle session. In this case, i think you can use this function to handle you question :

```
- (void)fbDidlogout
{
    // your code to get login screen here!
}
```

This function will called when the request logout has succeeded. Hope this will help, Cheers

Comment: But I dont have idea how to call login screen bcoz at the application launch it starts from -(BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI{.Can u please tell me how.?When Logout is clicked it will  change the button text to login.Now when Login is clicked it should redirect to login screen of facebook.